# Python strings split and assign to variable

Tags: python

I am trying to get google images's url using python. I used to google_images_download module to it. I have get code in stack overflow.

```
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper

from google_images_download import google_images_download
import sys


old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TextIOWrapper(BytesIO(), sys.stdout.encoding)


response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

arguments = {
    "keywords": "stackoverflow",
    "limit": 3,
    "print_urls": True,
    "size": "large",
}
paths = response.download(arguments)

sys.stdout.seek(0)
output = sys.stdout.read()

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = old_stdout

for line in output.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("Image URL:"):
        s = line.replace("Image URL: ", "")
        print(s)
```

print(s) in last line is print three links of images. I want assign that three links to different variables. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a list of URLs:

```py
url_list = []
for line in output.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("Image URL:"):
        s = line.replace("Image URL: ", "")
        url_list.append(s)
```

Comment: It is not working. Can you run this code please? I was tried print(url_list). But it prints
['link of first image']
['link of first image', 'link of second image']
['link of first image', 'link of second image', 'link of third image']

Comment: If I run it my `output` looks like this: `'\nItem no.: 1 --> Item name = stackoverflow\nEvaluating...\nStarting Download...\n\n\nUnfortunately all 3 could not be downloaded because some images were not downloadable. 0 is all we got for this search filter!\n\nErrors: 0\n\n'`. What does yours look like?

Comment: I replace this code 
`url_list = []
for line in output.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("Image URL:"):
        s = line.replace("Image URL: ", "")
        url_list.append(s)`
to this code
`for line in output.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith("Image URL:"):
        s = line.replace("Image URL: ", "")
        print(s)`

Then I get output like this
`['link of first image']
['link of first image', 'link of second image']
['link of first image', 'link of second image', 'link of third image']`